# Apache problem with hostname on OSX 10.8.4

Tags: network, macports, apache, macos

After updating to 10.8.4 I am having trouble running my macports apache server.  I stop the built-in apache with: `sudo apachectl stop`, then I try to start macports apache with: `sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start` and I get:

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using My-Name-iMac.local for ServerName
httpd (pid 98) already running
```

and when I load `localhost` in the browser I get **Unable to Connect...**

I'm just running this as a development machine, so I don't need a domain name.  The output of `hostname` (before and after this) is `My-Name-iMac.local` as you'd expect.  What concerns me is the `httpd (pid 98) already running` part of this output.

`which  apachectl` outputs `/usr/sbin/apachectl`

Comment: I think you should find a way to fix the output of `hostname` so as to get your real FQDN. I'm convinced this is neither a `Macports` nor an `Apache` problem.

Comment: I'm using this as a development environment.  I've never used FQDNs on development environments before and its never been a problem.  I didn't have one before the upgrade either.  Apple changed the way "web sharing" works in 10.8, and this is the source of the problem I think.

Comment: I'll also point out that I'm not trying to connect using a FQDN.

Comment: → iPadDeveloper2011: clear. You should add this information about a local dev. environnement within your original question: so as to avoid irrelevant suggestions as mine ☺ (*most* HTTP servers have to be connected to the Internet). Is `ping My-Name-iMac.local` OK? Could you add the opuput of `hostname` within your original question?

Comment: Hi @daniel.  Updated question as you suggest.  Yes, `ping My-Name-iMac.local` seems to be OK.  Interesting this is that it still works no problem after `sudo apachectl stop`...!?

Comment: I've noticed some weird behaviour.  It seemed like I'd found the solution when I tried: `sudo apachectl -k stop`--now I can start `/opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl` OK (although `sudo apachectl stop` also works now!?).  Trying to find which root folder was active, I changed my `index.html` files to display their path.  However `localhost` displayed an `index.html` that I could not find (in FireFox--refresh, reload, f5 to no avail)!?  However, `localhost/index.html` was `opt/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html`.  Trying `localhost` in chrome was OK, now FireFox OK too!?

Comment: After first having success only with `sudo apachectl -k stop`, it now seems I can switch between servers using `sudo apachectl stop` and `/opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start`, and then back with `/opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl stop` and `sudo apachectl start` no problem. However when I'm running the built-in apache (with `sudo apachectl start`) I see a `localhost/index.html` file in all browsers that doesn't appear to exist anywhere. (certainly not in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`)

Comment: OK, I had `/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.htm` (`.htm` not `.html` in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`).  Although this has been OK before, it was a problem now for some reason.  Creating `/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html` displayed OK in `localhost`, however when renaming that (`/Library/WebServer/Documents/index2.html`) browsers went back to displaying the non-existent index.html as localhost.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seemed to slowly evaporate when I started using `sudo apachectl -k stop` (though this could be just coincidence).  It now seems I can switch between servers using

`sudo apachectl stop` and `/opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start`,

and then back with

`/opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl stop` and `sudo apachectl start`

no problem.  I haven't been able to find any documentation on `apachectl -k` (beyond `apachectl help`).